# AngularJS returning data after two API calls

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

Ok this might be a bit complicated. I created this service to handle api calls:

```
.service('HttpHandler', ['ErrorService', function (service) {

    // Function to handle promises
    this.loadData = function (promise) {

        // Declare our model
        var model = {
            data: null,
            loading: true,
            promise: promise,
            error: null
        };

        // If our promise succeeds
        promise.then(function (response) {

            // Store the data
            model.data = response.data.result || response.data;
        }, function (error) {

            // Process our error
            model.error = service.process(error);
        });

        // Finally
        promise.finally(function () {

            // Set our loading flag to false regardless if there is an error or not
            model.loading = false;
        });

        // Return our model
        return model;
    };
}])
```

This allows me to access the data in my controller along with an errors, etc.
This works well in my application and is used throughout.

My login controller looks like this:

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$state', '$stateParams', 'AccountService', function ($state, $stateParams, service) {
    var self = this;

        // Get our return Url
        returnState = $stateParams.returnState,
        returnParams = $stateParams.returnParams;

    // Our login model
    self.model = {
        userName: '',
        password: ''
    };

    // The login function
    self.loginUser = function (valid) {

        // Check to see if our form is valid
        if (!valid)
            return;

        // Login
        self.login = service.login(self.model);

        // If we login properly
        self.login.promise.then(function (response) {

            // If we have a return Url
            if (returnState) {

                // Go to that url
                $state.go(returnState, returnParams);
            } else {

                // Otherwise, Redirect to the home page
                $state.go('dashboard');
            }
        });
    };
}])
```

and as you can see, it uses the above handler to do things (also in the view there is a directive handling any errors). Hopefully that is easy to understand.
Now, here comes the complicated bit.

I **had** my login function working nicely like this:

```
// Function to login
self.login = function (model) {

    // Set our data
    var data = 'grant_type=password&userName=' + model.userName + '&password=' + model.password;

    // Use the handler to login
    var login = handler.loadData($http.post('/oauth/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }));

    // If the user is logged in
    login.promise.then(function (response) {

        // Assign our object to our user variable
        var user = { token: response.data.access_token, userName: model.userName, authenticated: true };

        // Store our user in the cookie
        $cookies.user = angular.toJson(user);

        // Store our current user in the $rootScope
        $rootScope.user = user;
    });

    // Return the handled api request
    return login;
};
```

You can see here that it returns the **login** without worrying about the code that is being execute inside this function. But, I want to now make a change to this function to actually get some data from the user. I have changed it to this:

```
// Function to login
self.login = function (model) {

    // Set our data
    var data = 'grant_type=password&userName=' + model.userName + '&password=' + model.password;

    // Use the handler to login
    var login = handler.loadData($http.post('/oauth/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }));

    // If the user is logged in
    login.promise.then(function (response) {

        // Assign our object to our user variable
        var user = { token: response.data.access_token, userName: model.userName, authenticated: true };

        // Create our request
        var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/users',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
            },
            params: { username: model.userName }
        };

        // Get the current user
        $http(request).then(function (response) {

            // Get our data
            var data = response.data;

            // Assign our new data to our user object
            user.roles = data.roles;
            user.companyId = data.companyId;

            // Store our user in the cookie
            $cookies.user = angular.toJson(user);

            // Store our current user in the $rootScope
            $rootScope.user = user;
        });
    });

    // Return the handled api request
    return login;
};
```

Now the problem I have here is that I don't want it to return **login** until after the user information has been parsed.